# Unexpected SQL type encountered in calc_string_size

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm using "sqlsrv" extension for PHP.

A few days ago, I have no problem.

But today I have a problem with some queries! Some simple queries. Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_users
```

Of course when I run the query in SQL Server Management Studio, I have no problem. But when I run in PHP, I get this fatal error:

> Unexpected SQL type encountered in calc_string_size

Versions:

- SQL Server 2016
- PHP 7.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your fields is `sql_variant` type.

You can cast your field to `nvarchar` or `varchar`.

Comment: Thanks. You keep wasting my time.